# I can't update my rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I am a rails  beginner,now I follow the guide and create a test project as below:

admin_controller.rb

```
def blogEdit
  @btnName = "更新"
  @submitURL = "blogUpdate"
  @blog=Blog.find(params[:id])
end

def blogUpdate
  @blog=Blog.find(params[:id])
  @blog.update(params[:blog])
  redirect_to "/admin/blogList"
end
```

blogEdit.slim

```
= render "blogForm"
```

_blogForm.slim

```
=form_for :blog,url:{action: @submitURL} do |f|
=f.label  :title ,"标题"
=f.text_field :title 
=f.label  :body ,"内容"
=f.text_area :body,rows:10,style:'width:500px;'
=f.label  :author ,"作者"
=f.text_field :author
=f.hidden_field :id
=f.submit @btnName,class:'btn'
```

but when I update a blog,I get the error:

```
Couldn't find Blog without an ID
Rails.root: /home/hxh/share/ruby/myblog

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/admin_controller.rb:28:in `blogUpdate'

Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
  "authenticity_token"=>"3SBp+xSft8SzA5poczxNSU1zKReO2OpZQqgESn6ZURs=",
   "blog"=>{"title"=>"违法的",
   "body"=>"的说法都是",
   "author"=>"似懂非懂",
   "id"=>"2"},
```

"commit"=>"更新"}

so It shows that I not get the `params[:id]`

```
@blog=Blog.find(params[:id])
```

I had follow the guide,why I got the result?

Comment: `@blog=Blog.find(params[:blog])` should be   `@blog=Blog.find(params[:id])`

Comment: I am sorry ,but it also get the error.

Comment: What is the URL that you are trying to visit to edit the blogs. Do you have any blogs saved in the database?

Comment: What are your routes? Does your route have the :id segment? Also, you should name it just edit or update since the controller typically dictate your model.

Comment: my edit page is `/admin/blogEdit`,update URL is `/admin/blogUpdate`, when I submit this form,I get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing `=f.hidden_field :id` into form. So your `id` in in `params[:blog][:id]`.
But `id` have to be passing via `@submitURL`. Judging by your params `@submitUrl` aren't contains `id` of the blog.

You are not following guide convensions or your guide doesn't do it. Because there is common rules for name actions. It's `edit` and `update` instead your `blogEdit` and `blogUpdate`.

Answer (score 0):

The url that is created while submitting is not resourceful instead the URL should be created like /2/blogupdate but in your case it is /blogupdate.

What you can do here change these lines

```
def blogEdit
  @btnName = "更新"
  @submitURL = "/#{params[:id]}/blogUpdate"
  @blog=Blog.find(params[:id])
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In your form, instead of `@submitURL`, why don't you use `blogUpdate_blog_path(@blog)`?